# Relative positioning: how to avoid the discentering of external images?

Tags: graphics, positioning, crop

Stuck with the following problem while making "Who we are" section for a business plan.  The code

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt,align=center},path image/.style={align=center,
path picture={align=center,
\node at (path picture bounding box.center) {
\includegraphics[width=5cm]{#1}
};}}]
\centering
\node[circle,align=center,minimum size=4cm,path image=frog.jpg,draw=white,ultra thin] (bergkamp) {};
\node[text width=4cm,below=of bergkamp] (bergkampbio) {Dennis Bergkamp \\ founder  \\ \textit{Amsterdam graduate} \\ \textit{Harvard professor}};

\node[circle,align=center,minimum size=4cm,right=of bergkamp,path image=frog.jpg,draw=white,ultra thin] (henry) {};
\node[text width=4cm,below=of henry] (henrybio) {Thierry Henry \\ cofounder \\ \textit{Princeton graduate} \\ \textit{USTC professor}};

\node[circle,minimum size=4cm,path image=frog.jpg,draw=white,ultra thin,right=of henry] (pires) {};
\node[text width=4cm,below=of pires] (piresbio) {Robert Pires \\ assistant \\ \textit{PhD student} \\ \textit{HSE, Math department}};

\node[circle,align=center,minimum size=4cm,path image=frog.jpg,draw=white,ultra thin,below=of bergkampbio] (vieira) {};
\node[text width=4cm,below=of vieira] (vieibio) {Partick Vieira \\ team lead \\ \textit{University of Milano} \\ \textit{Imperial College} };

\node[circle,align=center,minimum size=4cm,path image=frog.jpg,draw=white,ultra thin,below=of henrybio] (keane) {};
\node[text width=4cm,below=of keane] (keanobio) {Roy Keane \\ marketing \\ \textit{University of Nottingham} \\ \textit{Manchester fellow} };


\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

provides

[image: Our team]

Obviously five <strike>frogs</strike> faces are wanted. Another issue is, the whole picture is not properly centered (margins on the left are bigger then margins on the right), but I think it's relatively easy to fix it playing with `0.33*\textwidth`.

Comment: I'm not sure it's good idea to edit the question - using frogs it is much more visual what's going on (saying it after a try with `example-image-a`). In order to play with it you just have to substitute `path image=frog.jpg` by `path image=example-image-a` in five places. That won't take longer than 10 seconds.

Comment: You can post the image and say you've substituted `example-whatever` in the code. Or you can use the tiger which is in standard distributions... Note that the image is too wide for A4 when I compile it. You can cheat to make it centred but it is too wide. Also, it makes no sense to use `\centering` inside a `tikzpicture`.

Comment: Got it, thank you. Didn't know about the standard tiger picture.

Comment: Yes. It is handy: `texmf-dist/doc/generic/pstricks/images/tiger.eps` and elsewhere. Though it would be more convenient if all of the copies were not under `doc/` ;).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
% !TEX TS-program = pdflatex
% !TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode
% arara: pdflatex: { synctex: true }
\pdfminorversion=7

\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{tikz,graphicx}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}
  {\centering
    \makebox[0pt]{%
      \begin{tikzpicture}
        [
        every node/.style={
          inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt,align=center
        },
        path image/.style n args=2{
          path picture={
            \node (#1) at (path picture bounding box.center) {\includegraphics[width=5cm]{#2}};
          },
          draw=red,
          ultra thin
        }
        ]
        \path [path image={bergkamp}{tiger}] circle (20mm);
        \node[text width=4cm,below=of bergkamp] (bergkampbio) {Dennis Bergkamp \\ founder  \\ \textit{Amsterdam graduate} \\ \textit{Harvard professor}};
        \path  [path image={henry}{tiger}] ([xshift=25mm]bergkamp.east)  circle (20mm);
        \node[text width=4cm,below=of henry] (henrybio) {Thierry Henry \\ cofounder \\ \textit{Princeton graduate} \\ \textit{USTC professor}};
        \path  [path image={pires}{tiger}] ([xshift=25mm]henry.east)  circle (20mm);
        \node[text width=4cm,below=of pires] (piresbio) {Robert Pires \\ assistant \\ \textit{PhD student} \\ \textit{HSE, Math department}};
        \path  [path image={vieira}{tiger}] ([yshift=-25mm]bergkampbio.south)  circle (20mm);
        \node[text width=4cm,below=of vieira] (vieibio) {Partick Vieira \\ team lead \\ \textit{University of Milano} \\ \textit{Imperial College} };
        \path  [path image={keane}{tiger}] ([yshift=-25mm]henrybio.south)  circle (20mm);
        \node[text width=4cm,below=of keane] (keanobio) {Roy Keane \\ marketing \\ \textit{University of Nottingham} \\ \textit{Manchester fellow} };
      \end{tikzpicture}}\par}
\end{document}
```

[image: tigers]

Comment: Pure, pure beauty!

So that's the `\path` command who saves the day. And the skilled hands of maestro @cfr, of course.

Comment: @AlexGarkusha So it seems. I'm glad you asked this because I didn't know anything about `path picture`. My first thought was that you couldn't put a `\node` in a style like that. But I think you just can't put a `\node` in a style and then apply that to a `\node`. E.g. getting the `circle` as a node shape and trying to use that as the path doesn't seem to work - you need the `circle` to be the path itself. Or something like that...!

Comment: @AlexGarkusha 'So it seems' applies to the comment about the `\path`, of course. I don't seem to be a maestro... ;).

Comment: The `path picture` technique was adopted from the glorious humongous [pgfmanual](http://ctan.uni-altai.ru/graphics/pgf/base/doc/pgfmanual.pdf), page 174 — I didn't know any other place with image-cropping code.